# No results returned when doing Facebook Query

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get a list of aid (album ids) using a Facebook Query.

**What Works:**

Running the query from the browser returns results, but when I run it using Facebook Connect no values are returned.

The problem I'm having is specific the album object, I get results when querying the user table.

The only real difference I can think of is when running from the browser a access_token parameter is included, running from browser without this returns nothing.

**Authentication:**

I am using OAuth to authenticate as outlined here: [Mobile Apps - Getting Started](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) 
Do I need to include the access_token in the parameter list when doing a query?

**The Code:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"<myAppId>"];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:nil delegate:self];
    }

    NSArray* permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              @"email", @"read_stream", nil] retain];

    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];

    NSString *fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me()"];

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fql, @"query", @"json", @"format", nil];

    [facebook requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"GET" andDelegate:self];   

    return YES;
}
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        result = [result objectAtIndex:0];  }

    NSLog(@"didLoad() received result: %@", result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely need to include the `access_token` field. We verify that the access token has access to the user_photos permission before allowing you access to that user's data.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, had to change a couple of things based on your answer. I've added the user_photos permission. `NSArray* permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
         @"email", @"read_stream", @"user_photos", nil] retain];` and the access_token paramater `NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fql, @"query", @"json", @"format", facebook.accessToken, @"access_token", nil];`